# XML restrict to 0-4 initials

Tags: xml

How can I create a XML schema that restricts to 0-4 letters?  For example, this only allows 4.  No more or less.

```
<xs:element name="initials">
 <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

The XML would look like this

```
<initials>ABC</initials>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 0-4 ASCII upper case letters you could use

```
[A-Z]{0,4}
```

`\p{Lu}` instead of `[A-Z]` would allow for any Unicode upper-case letter character, rather than restricting only to ASCII.

[This page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html) is a good summary of exactly what regular expression features are and are not available in the dialect used by XML Schema.

Comment: Yeah, thanks that works.  I thought it was something like that but could not find the tight syntax.  I tried {0-4}